# Usability features for JComboBox within JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecelleditor

I'm trying to build a table which includes JComboBoxes as both the renderer and editor components. This mostly works fine, however there are two things I can't seem to solve.

1. Tabbing between cells should make the JComboBox active
2. Clicking the drop-down arrow should immediately open the option list

Regarding 1, the editable combo should place focus within the embedded text field, the fixed combo should allow the down arrow to open the list of options.

Regarding 2, I find that this sometimes works depending on what other cell is currently active, but other times I have to double click. I cannot make this behaviour consistent.

For convenience I have included a clear example which (I believe) uses the recommended approach for embedding JComboBoxes within Jtables.

Thank you for constructive advice.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableCombos
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        AbstractTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel()
        {
            String[] columnHeaders = new String[]{"label", "combo-edit", "combo-fixed"};
            Class<?>[] columnClasses = new Class<?>[]{String.class, Double.class, Double.class};
            List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
            {
                data.add(new Object[]{"row 1", 1.0d, 2.0d});
                data.add(new Object[]{"row 2", 2.0d, 3.0d});
            }

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount()
            {
                return columnHeaders.length;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
            {
                return column != 0;
            }

            @Override
            public int getRowCount()
            {
                if (data == null) // race condition
                    return 0;
                return data.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int row, int column)
            {
                return data.get(row)[column];
            }

            @Override
            public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column)
            {
                data.get(row)[column] = aValue;
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                return columnClasses[column];
            }

            @Override
            public String getColumnName(int column)
            {
                return columnHeaders[column];
            }
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke(true);

        TableColumn c1 = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
        TableColumn c2 = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);

        JComboBox<Double> editorComboEditable = new JComboBox<>(new Double[]{1.0d, 2.0d, 3.0d});
        editorComboEditable.setEditable(true);
        c1.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(editorComboEditable));
        c2.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(new JComboBox<>(new Double[]{1.0d, 2.0d, 3.0d})));

        final JComboBox<Double> rendererComboEditable = new JComboBox<>(new Double[]{1.0d, 2.0d, 3.0d});
        rendererComboEditable.setEditable(true);
        final JComboBox<Double> rendererComboFixed = new JComboBox<>(new Double[]{1.0d, 2.0d, 3.0d});
        c1.setCellRenderer(new TableCellRenderer()
        {
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable t, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
            {
                rendererComboEditable.setSelectedItem(value);
                return rendererComboEditable;
            }
        });
        c2.setCellRenderer(new TableCellRenderer()
        {
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable t, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
            {
                rendererComboFixed.setSelectedItem(value);
                return rendererComboFixed;
            }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I have included a clear example"*  Nice example.  To be nicer though, it is good to resolve (include) the imports.  I typically find that all of `java.awt`, `java.awt.event` & `javax.swing` can be imported without clashes, so that is just 3 more lines of code to get a GUI example compilable with no 'ifs or buts'..

Comment: thanks @AndrewThompson i was trying to keep it short and simple. have included imports and class dec.

Comment: Hmm.. `List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<>();`  Is that a Java 7 thing where you can leave out the 2nd type?  E.G. `List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<Object[]>();` compiles in Java 6. I'm getting 4 compile errors here for 4 statements of the shorter form.

Comment: yes sorry, using a few J7 features. should be fairly easy to resolve? you could just leave generics out maybe?

Answer (score 3):

Both of your issues be resolved by overriding the `DefaultCellEditor#isCellEditable` method and returning `true`

You may need to set `JTable#setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke` to true as well

**Update**

The short answer is "It's messy". The long answer is "it's very messy"

I did a "continuos editing" process some time back. Basically, I overrode the <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> key bindings.

What I'd did was basically stop any active cell editor, take note of the current cell and then tried to finding the next editable cell, looping back around to the start (cell 0x0) if required.

When I found a editable cell, I called `JTable#editCellAt` to start editing the cell.

To get the popup to be visible when the cell starts editing, you will need to override the `addNotify` method of the `JComboBox` and, using `SwingUtilities#invokeLater`, set the popup visible

Comment: @mkorbel Thats a great addition, but if your return true from isCelleEditable, then it doesn't matter as any keyboard or mouse event will start editing ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks i'll give this a try and report back soon

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for the tips - indeed i had forgotten to add isCellEditable and I didn't know about setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke however after adding both of these appropriately the behaviour is not quite right. 1. tabbing into the 'fixed' combos the user needs to hit space before the down arrow will trigger the dropdown. is there a way to make this automatic? 2. if you open the option list for either of the combos in row 2 then click the down arrow in the combo directly above it, the option list does not open. maybe because the combos use the same editor? can this be resolved?

Comment: Point 2 - this has more to do with the fact that the active cell editor hasn't stopped editing yet.  As to a way to fix it, I'm not quite sure.

Comment: ^ its actually because the 'focusLost' event is being fired after the mouse event has opened the popup. So because it is the same component as the one which just lost focus, it is subsequently closed.

Comment: Thanks for the information about `JTable#setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke`.  I hadn't known about that method, but it is solving my issue where I want to allow a JComboBox in a JTable to be usable without the mouse.